# kernel message, who knows what this means

Tags: virtualbox, pfsense, kernel

kernel: [2427107.300793] traps: ATA-0 [27274] trap int3 ip:7f2c48115064 sp:7f2c22e9ad90 error:0 in VBoxDD.so[7f2c480ec000+155000]

the message is recorded in the virtualbox host system

when this comes up, pfSense VM crashes

Answer (score 2):

This is an interruption trap caused by the ATA disk management from VirtualBox.

That comes from the Linux kernel, as it was running the code at `7f2c48115064` (Instruction Pointer) and the Stack Pointer was pointing at `7f2c22e9ad90` (not that's it's much of help!).

It could either be an actual problem with the disk (or virtual disk) that VBox utilizes, or could be a breakpoint or a voluntary triggered trap set by a developer.

That could also mean there is some config problem (using ATA vs SATA etc...), or the Host preventing the Guest from accessing the resource (disk allocated to VBox), eg an Antivirus, access rights, special flags (`chattr`), etc.